# I lack the "model" meny inside mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench, google-cloud-storage

I get the model menu if I create a new model, but not in the tab of my created database.

I've put and connected the database in google cloud.

Do I have to import or export the database in order to get the "model"-menu and be able to do diagrams and such?

Also in my installed version (6.3) of workbench I don't get the white tri-partscreen that's in all the videos and screenshots, only the black screen with the models and connections.

Answer (score 1):

The "tri-part" screen was removed in Workbench 6.0. For details, see ["What is new in Workbench 6.0"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-what-is-new-60.html)

As for modeling, keep in mind that modeling is a separate operation from your database. In other words, people can create and edit models without a MySQL Server, and later synchronize (forward engineer) the model with (to) the MySQL database. Or, one can create a model from a database (reverse engineer), edit the model, then synchronize it back to the database. For details, see ["Forward and Reverse Engineering](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-design-engineering.html)